# sending email through port no 443 or 80

Tags: email

i am a college student. My college network blocks all the port other than 80 and 443.
Now i am doing my project and i need to send a email. Is there any way i can send email through these ports

### Edit

I got a way around this problem. I used google appengine as a relay. Whenever i want to send a mail i will send a post request to the appengine and  the servlet in the  appengine will send the mail.

Comment: you send email via HTTP and HTTPS ouch!

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a reasonable question, clearly stated.

Comment: @Jeremy: yes but not programming related at all.

Comment: @RageZ - writing a routine to send an email is definitely programming related...

Comment: At least move it to serverfault or superuser... why just close it all together?

Answer (score 3):

No, those are for HTTPS and HTTP. Your college blocks those ports specifically so that you *can't* send email: otherwise it would be spam!

You'll need to ask your tutor for directions on what to do. Most likely the ports are blocked at the firewall outside of campus, but you can use those ports inside your lab or campus network.

If you really need to send mail to the outside world, check the configuration of your email client - that will have the details of the campus outgoing SMTP server that you need.

Comment: Nothing constrains a network port to any particular traffic - port 80 doesn't guarantee that a webserver can be expected at the address.

Comment: Naturally. But it would be a very strange situation to have an SMTP server listening on port 80 or 443.

Answer (score 1):

Send it via your network's outgoing mail server.  That's what it's there for.

(There should be an SMTP server set up somewhere on your college network, listening on port 25 and relaying mail to the outside world).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows? If so you can actually configure your IIS SMPTP server to send mails from a different port. Go to IIS Manager then Right-click on the SMTP virtual server and select properties, under the General tab, click on the advanced button and edit the desired IP addresses which you would like to make the port change on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This setting doesn't change the port that *receiving* SMTP servers listen on, port 25.